# Checking if anything besides numbers exists

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<input type='text' />` element and user have to insert a number.
How do I check if `value` contains something besides numbers? (*nothing* but numbers allowed)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any effort? This should be as simple as get the value, and check if it's a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Regex

```
var regEx = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhwLQ/)

```
var num = 'AA'
var regEx = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
alert(regEx.test(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML 5 [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern): `<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />`

`\d*` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that reads as "a digit zero or more times."

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery - $.isNumeric(value)

Answer (score 0):

When a user have entered something, input looses focus, so try this:

```
    $('input:text').blur(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.match(new RegExp("[^0-9]", "g")) != null){
        alert("Not only numbers entered!");
    }
});
```

this means: when focus lost we try to find a non numeric values in the inputed value

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best for this situation, but:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup=" if( !+this.value && +this.value != 0 ){ this.value = '' }" />
```

Pretty much `+this.value` checks if the value is a number, or it returns `NaN`. And if its `NaN` then it erases the field.

edit: added `&&` for '0' my mistake